# set src attribute in google vr view for web

Tags: php, google-visualization, virtual, google-vr

I want to use Google vrview-web using this example: [googlevrview](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web)
How can I set `src` attribute in `iframe` tag?

Below is the example given in the link:

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/index.html?video=examples/video/congo_2048.mp4&is_stereo=true"></iframe>
```

Now I have to set my video URL in src like below:

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen src="<?php echo VIDEO_URL.$data["video"]; ?>&is_stereo=true"></iframe>
```

It does not display the video.

if I use below `iframe` tag:

```
<iframe width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowfullscreen src="https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/index.html?video=MY_VIDEO&is_stereo=true"></iframe>
```

Still, it prints this data in my page:

[Output](https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/index.html)

Comment: what is the resulting iframe tag lookings like

Comment: it is printing the whole HTML of the current page

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the VIDEO_URL hold this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/index.html?video=
```

Your iframe can't just print the HTML. Please inspect your rendered HTML/DOM or iframe src value is proper and not broken.

Moreover it is required that your website, where the videos are, allows CORS. Cross origin resource sharing. Otherwise the Google's script won't load your video inside the iframe in VR mode.

Comment: `Cross origin resource sharing` means what?

Comment: how to enable that?

Comment: and video is on my server then why should i use google's path?

Comment: also enabled *CORS* `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: have you published the required vrview libraries on your server? if yes then you don't need to enable CORS... if you have not yet copied and are using from Google inside an iFrame then you do need to append with Google's path as shown in their example. However if you have published vrview to your website, why would you even need an iFrame? See Self-hosting section at [link](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web)